# How to convert SQL date to a string in Lua?

Tags: sql, lua

I saved a date in my SQL database with function "NOW()" by a query, but now if I fetch it via SQL query I get a number (example: 1473080879). Any idea on how to fetch a real date from SQL and put it into a string? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.date(format, time)` Example:

```
local dateString = os.date("MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS")
```

But you can do it also in SQL using (MySQL):

```
DATE_FORMAT(field, '%d/%m/%Y %T')
```

[MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`Date_format(fieldname,%Y-%m-%d) as FieldName` for example [The Docs/Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) will show you various ways you may want to display the date.

ok maybe you need `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1473080879);` instead...

[FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Hi, so I did this:

**DATE_FORMAT(`posted`, '%Y-%m-%e') as date**

But this is the output I get: 

**userdata: 02140138**

Comment: Maybe you need `from_UnixTime(FieldName)` instead.